# MySQL compare and extract the duplicate part of two strings

Tags: mysql, regex, string, performance, split

Currently I have two strings like this:

```
'1,2,3,4,5' and '3,6,7,5,8,4,9'
```

I would like to have the result like this one: `'3,4,5'`, which is the common ids from the two strings. Is there any quick way to achieve this? I could split the strings and do a loop through each but this will take a lot of time and resources when the two strings are too large, like long text. I am looking at regex but I don't know how to achieve this. Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normalize your data. Only then `INNER JOIN` would be a help.

Comment: CSV doesn't work very well in MySQL (or any RDBMS for the most part).  You can look into a function called [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but this would only solve half your problem.

Comment: Yeah, please don't use regex for this one. There are tools better suited for this task, such as what @1000111 suggested.

Comment: If you intend to use an RDBMS for this, then normalisation is the only option